# How to check if application is running

Tags: c#, process

I just want to check if any desired application is already running or not

for eg suppose I have VLC or iTunes or any windows application then how can i figure it out by c# code if it is running or not.

Answer (score 41):

This should be pretty easy to find with a quick Google search, but here you go:

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)
{
    // Is running
}
```

Replace `process_name` with the name of the process you are looking for (i.e. `vlc`).

**Checking for Self-Process**

As pointed out in the comments by *@filimonic*, if you want to check whether more than one instance of the application is running you can use `> 1` in place of `> 0`:

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 1)
{
    // Is running
}
```

This works by checking that a maximum of 1 processes is currently running.

Comment: You should specify >1 if it is self process

Comment: Just to remove question 'What am I doing wrong, it says another instance is running'. When you start process with name 'proc.exe', you will get Length >= 1, not 0 (process counts itself). Just to make it cleaner

Comment: I guess the `>0` or `>1` is based on if you're checking if another instance of your own application is running already, right? In case of checking if another process is running, I would even suggest using `LinQ`'s `Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Any()` which seems cleaner for me.

Comment: This is the google search result :)

Comment: Using System.Diagnostics;

Answer (score 4):

you can use either `Process.GetProcessesByName` if you know the process name or `Process.GetProcessesByID` if you know it's ID.